# Discover the Male ratio per occupation and sort it from the most to the least

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, data-analysis

table link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/u.user
(separator=|)
I have solved it
my code

```
a=users.groupby(['occupation','gender']).gender.count()
b=users.groupby('occupation').gender.count()
c=(a/b)*100
c.sort_values(ascending=False).xs('M',level=1)
```

But in question it is required to Use numpy.where() to encode gender column, which I unable to do.
How to solve it by Using numpy.where() to encode gender column

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
users['is_male'] = np.where(users.gender == 'M', 1, 0)

(users.groupby('occupation').is_male.sum()/users.groupby('occupation').gender.count()).round(2).sort_values(ascending = False)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.